# Crope image by line

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, drawing

Could anyone help me out if it is possible on `objective-C` to crop image by drawing line. I am looking for the solution a couple days and no found anything yet.

Couple days I was unsuccessfully fighting with this task myself. The point is - we have draw the line between 2 points for example, which is intersect the layer with image, the goal is cut this image on two parts by this line. Thank you.

[image: Cropping image by line.]

Comment: **Yes, that is possible**. What you have tried to implement it?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have a thorough look at [CAShapeLayers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/) and the Framework around it - if you come across any serious problems along the way, feel free to ask a more specific question actually related to programming.

Comment: @JanGreve I am not looking easy ways, but I've tried this, can you share any examples or explain? Thank you.

Comment: ok, I will looking on CAShapeLayers, maybe I miss something, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JanGreve just turn me in the right direction, I need create the spline related with my line and picture part I want to crop, and picture part I can choose using 
"fillColor" from  CAShapeLayers only then I can use mask utility, or I am wrong?

Comment: OP, if I understand you correctly, you're right. Also, you are on the right track there.

Comment: ok, I will try to create closed area, Thank you!

Comment: I am stuck guys, I can't create close paths from intersecting line and leaf layer...and I really need help, not enough time to create algorithm and cropping this image, I've spend too much time on this task, any examples? I don't ask you about complete answer, just how you see this situation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can achieve your goal in many ways. As a example, see "Masking an Image with an Image Mask" and "Masking an Image by Clipping the Context" topics in "Quartz 2D Programming Guide/Bitmap Images and Image Masks".